# ModelState reference is different when accessed from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, modelstate

I have a Controller class called **ServiceController** whose ModelState is being passed as a reference into an instance of another validation class called **RequestValidator**. When ServiceController receives a request, its RequestValidator class instance checks to see if the ModelState is valid or not. Problem is, for an erroneous input, the `IsValid` value for the ServiceController's own ModelState returns `false` (which is expected), but the `IsValid` value for Validator's ModelState is `true`.

Here's some code on how the two classes are setup:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
public class ServiceController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly RequestValidator validator;

    //This is the ServiceController's contructor:
    public ServiceController(RequestValidator validator)
    {
        //A validator instance is passed in, which is used by this ServiceController instance
        this.validator = validator;
        
        //The validator's ModelState is set to point to the ModelState of the ServiceController
        this.validator.ModelState = this.ModelState; // This is the ONLY point in my ServiceController code where validator.ModelState is written to
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("v0.1/users")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> ProvisionUser(
        [FromBody] UserProvisioningRequest userRequest)
    {
        //But when an erroneous request comes, both ModelStates give different IsValid value:
        
        //The following two variables should have same value, but they don't at runtime.
        bool thisModelStateValidation = this.ModelState.IsValid;
        bool validatorModelStateValidation = this.validator.ModelState.IsValid;
        
        //The hashcodes of both ModelStates are also different
        int thisModelStateHashCode = this.ModelState.GetHashCode();
        int validatorModelStateHashCode = this.requestPayloadValidator.ModelState.GetHashCode();

        this.validator.ValidateRequest(userRequest);
    }
}


public class RequestValidator
{
    public ModelStateDictionary ModelState { get; set; }

    public void ValidateRequest(UserProvisioningRequest userRequest)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid) // ---> At this point, IsValid is true, whereas it should be false
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in a code comment above, even the hash codes of both ModelStates are different. But I don't understand why this is so because the value of `this.validator.ModelState` is always written to ONCE. The only way this can be explained is if `this.ModelState` gets reset somehow, but I don't see why that would happen.

Comment: The code looks good for me, and also failed to reproduce this issue. If you can share a mini code sample on GitHub, I can help looking into this issue.

Comment: I reproduced with ASP.NET Core 5. Just set a object ID on `this.ModelState` in the controller's constructor and in the controller's action. This generate 2 ID because this is two distinct instances of `ModelState`. I don't know the reason, but I doubt it's a bug.

Comment: Maybe you can inject the controller in your validation class (or a delegate).